# What's the difference between #define and const int when declaring a pin?

Tags: programming, c++, ide

Over the course of my Arduino usage and learning, I've noticed that in some sketches people use the `#define` command to declare pins, while some others simply use `const int` for the same.

My question is, what's the difference between the two, and which one should be preferred for use?

Comment: I guess that you mean `#define` instead of `#include`. The more professional way to declare pins is `const int myPin = ...` This helps the compiler understand that it is a constant value and storage is not required. This is slightly better than `#define` as it gives the compile information about the data type.

Comment: @MikaelPatel exactly... so basically the `int` method is better right?

Comment: Yes. Please update the title and remove "include". That is something totally different and not related :)

Comment: I usually prefer to use `enum` for integer or character constants rather than either `#define` or `const int`.  See accepted answer to  [Is it better to use #define or const int for constants?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/506),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"#define" is a preprocessor directive. It defines a lable and a value, that will be positioned in the preprocessed-source-code at the same place of each occurence of the label. No type is defined, so it is a basic and dumb substitution of strings before compilation. It can then lead to errors or misunderstandings during compilation.

"const int xxx" defines a type, and locks the value of that instance. It's safer to use this method. The compiler can check for type errors and throw messages (or break compilation) if you made a mistake.

Example:

```
#define A 5
int dummy_integer = A
```

... will be preprocessed as...

```
int dummy_integer = 5
```

... and the compiler will read this statement.

However, if I remember good, you can always overwrite a preprocessor directive as follows:

```
#define A 5
int dummy_integer = A
//some code here
#undef A
#define A "my_string"
std::cout << A
```

That's not good. By using the "const" modifier, instead, you can't change the value (nor the type) of a variable (and so it's defined "constant").